# What does this bash script code do?

Tags: bash, shell, arguments

When use a script that will accept a file name, it starts and ends line numbers as arguments and displays all lines between the given line numbers.

What does following bash script code do ?

```
"sed -n $2,$3p $1"
```

Comment: See [ExplainShell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sed+-n+%242%2C%243p+%241), `$1`, `$2`, `$3` are the passed arguments.

Comment: Since you have the command inside quotes it will fail with: `command not found`. The opening `"` should come before the first $: `sed -n "$2,$3p"  "$1"`. If you don't use quotes around `$1` then a filename containing whitespace will break the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the goal is to print some lines of a file and call the *script*,

> first argument is the file, 2 argument is line to start with, 3
>   argument is line to finish with.

```
[script-name] [file-to-print-lines-from] [start-line] [end-line]

sed [number1],[number2]p [file]
```

Prints those line numbers from the file